# HP Pavillion Dv7 AC-Compatible Wi-Fi Chip?

Tags: laptop, wifi, wireless, bluetooth

I was reading the HP Dv7 service manual looking for a replacement wi-fi chip, and I think that my brother's chip finally kicked the bucket after around a decade of service.

I did all the usual monkeying around with drivers, and software but nothing works.

Anyway, I noticed that there were no recommendations for AC-compatible wi-fi chips in the manual.

I see that there are a lot of a/b/g/n, but nothing for the AC standard.

What should I look for in a wi-fi chip for a pavillion dv7 to optimize wi-fi performance? Is there an AC compliant chip that can be used with this computer without being rejected?

I'm looking only for chips that also support the bluetooth protocol.

Picture Here:
[image: Wi-Fi Chips]

Answer (score 1):

`Huffer` posted an excellent response on (https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/WLAN-Module-Recommendations/td-p/6872092)

He said that there are no AC-Compatible wi-fi chips available on my model number Dv7 due to a blacklisting of all other wi-fi chips that are non-manufacturer approved.

He also said that certain models are whitelisted and don't have this lack of forward compatibility.